# Reconnect redis when connection die in golang

Tags: go, redis

I'm try to build an app that have subscription with Redis PubSub. When the Redis instance got restarted the app will panic. I catch the panic and try to connect to redis. Currently i've implemented this:

```golang
// init redis connection
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1) // set initial wait group
go func() {
    // do redis connection in loop to always reconnect when connection is down
    recoverChannel := make(chan error)
    for {
        // this function will connect to redis and try for 3 times
        redis.InitRedisConnection()
        wg.Done() // done wait group

        // channel subscribtion goes here
        // this will panic if connection/subscription die
        go redis.SubscribeRedisChannel("channel", recoverChannel)

        // wait and listen on redis subscribtion failed
        // and do loop when it happens
        <-recoverChannel

        // add wait group to prevent negative wait group ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
        // if i remove this line it will throw error negative wait group when looping
        wg.Add(1)
    }
}()

// wait for redis connection before start http server
// this only wait for first wait group and not inside the loop above
wg.Wait()
```

Right now i'm not sure if my approach is correct. Any suggestion on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: "Right now i'm not sure if my approach is correct." Does it work as desired?

Comment: WDYT: remove the `WaitGroup`, call `redis.InitRedisConnection()` outside the goroutine the first time and then run "retry loop" in goroutine.

Comment: @larks yes it is, but it feel kinda wrong when call wg.add(1) while it not waited anymore

Comment: @medasx so I have to put `redis.InitRedisConnection()` twice, one outside the loop and one at the end of loop after `<-recoverChannel`?

Comment: you could loop over `recoverChannel` and call `connect` and `subscribe` in loop. This means that the first subscribe has to be called outside the loop too.